# How do you compile CodeShark/RippleGen?

Tags: c++

I would like to run the code below

https://github.com/CodeShark/RippleGen

How do I compile it so that I can run it?

I'm on Windows 7, if need be I can install Ubuntu on a VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile it by running `make` in the root directory of the repo.

You'll have to have GNU Make available on your box. I see that the makefile has the `-lssl -lcrypto -lboost_thread -lboost_system` libraries specified, so you will have to have openssl, libcrypto (you can get it if you install libssl-dev), and the boost libraries available.

I would personally be more comfortable to have this setup on Ubuntu - you can easily have the necessary packages there, but it should be possible on Windows as well, if you install cygwin.